# MongoDB (via Meteor) treats object property as string when updating a collection document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

My goal is to update a collection document with an object that contains a 'username' property with a 'rating' value. This object will be pushed to the 'ratings' array that already exists on the document.

For whatever reason, the property 'username' is treated as a string instead of its variable value. The 'rating' value is correctly being grabbed and pushed.

```
Template.Rating.events({
  'submit form': function (event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = template.find('form');
    var rating = template.find('input[name="rating"]:checked').value;
    var currentPun = Session.get('randomPun');
    var username = Meteor.user().username || null;

    console.log(username);
    Puns.update(
      { _id: currentPun._id},
      {
        $push: {
          // When pushing to ratings array, the {username: rating} object treats 'username' as a string instead of a variable.
          ratings: {username: rating}
        }
      }
    );
  }
});
```

I am confused because the console log midway down does log the correct username.

Anyway, as a result of whatever is happening, the 'ratings' array on the collection document looks something like this:

```
[{username: 3}, {username: 5}, {username: 2}, {username: 4}]
```

Instead of something like this:

```
[{joesmith: 3}, {janedoe: 5}, {kevincostner: 2}, {donaldtrump: 4}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With JavaScript objects, you cannot make the properly name a variable using the literal object notation. You must use the array notation.

So for your example, you would write:

```
var obj = {};

obj[username] = rating;

 Puns.update({ _id: currentPun._id}, {
    $push: {
      ratings: obj
    }
 });
```